# Link to specific image on fotorama

Tags: fotorama

I have some fotorama pictures and I want to get a link to an specific one. For example I'd like to go to the third image of the carousel with a link and not only to the first one. I guess I should use the .activeIndex but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the fotorama documentation.

Just add the attribute `data-hash="true"` to the enclosing fotorama div element:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-hash="true">
  <img src="1.jpg" id="photo_1">
  <img src="2.jpg" id="photo_2">
  <img src="3.jpg" id="photo_3">
  ... etc ...
</div>
```

and then link to them using the `id` attribute as a URL fragment identifier, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/my_gallery.html#photo_1
http://example.com/my_gallery.html#photo_2
http://example.com/my_gallery.html#photo_3
```

There are some examples you can play with here: http://fotorama.io/customize/hash/